# Android IAP getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus is not canceling the old subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement upgrading/downgrading subscriptions in my Android app.  I believe I have correctly implemented everything however it does not appear to be running correctly during my testing.

My app has three options: Monthly, 3-Month, and 6-Month subscription options. When I subscribe to any option I call the following function where 'sku' is the sku for the item being purchased and 'oldSkus' are the skus for the other items.

```
buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus(5,
          mContext.getPackageName(), oldSkus, sku, itemType, extraData);
```

When I subscribe to the 3-Month option it works great and the app correctly receives a 3-Month subscription Purchase from the Play Store.  If I attempt to upgrade to the 6-Month subscription the following flow occurs:

1. 'Change Subscription' dialog is prompted providing my 'Current Plan' and the 'New Plan' -> Click 'Continue'
2. Plan details are outlined. Click -> 'Subscribe' -> 'Confirm'
3. Transaction is successful and Purchase data is returned to the app.
4. Receive email claiming subscription was updated with details:

   - Previous Plan: 3 - Months : Canceled
   - New Plan: 6 - Months : Active Immediately
5. Go to Play Store account and view subscriptions

   - 3 Month Plan - Subscribed with Cancel button
   - 6 Month Plan - Subscribed with Cancel button
6. Launch app and observer getInventory results

   - 3 Month plan - User is subscribed
   - 6 Month plan - User is subscribed

As far as I can tell the old subscription was not correctly canceled by the Play Store.  My hope is that this is only happening because I am using a tester account and the $/day which occurs when testing subscriptions is causing some problems with the pro-rating.

UPDATE: Google has responded to my ticket and informed me that they have escalated the issue.  I will update again when I get another response.

Comment: I am testing this now, too. I am experiencing similar behaviour.

Comment: Call to the Google Play Developer Api is returning the subscription that should be canceled still returns autoRenewing = true.
Note that: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html states that the subscription is canceled (and according to https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel canceled (not revoked) subscriptions are valid until end of subscription, although it does not make much sense in the upgrade scenario). Would love some Google input on that.

Comment: Have you tried it in production maybe?

Comment: This:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html
states:
"Important: The refund and revoke methods do not support test purchases."
Maybe that's why the In-app Billing Sandbox does not support upgrade subscriptions (the old ones have to be revoked internally for the upgrade process to have sense).

Comment: Thank you for all your input @gswierczynski. I have yet to try production but I am in talks with Google and will hopefully have a solid answer soon.  Will keep this question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it with real money.
The old subscription got canceled (I think revoked in the way the Google Play understands it).
After upgrading the old subscription is no longer visible in the app details in Google Play App - only the new one is.

Although I am not sure how to recognise it with Google Play Developer API call - how to recognise that this old subscription is no longer valid.
The get method on Purchases.subscriptions resource does return autoRenew as false (which is good), but it is not enough to recognise that features for that subscription should no longer be available to user since the same happens when user cancels subscriptions and when user cancels subscriptions the features should still be available until the expiration period.

Unfortunately the expiration returned by the get call still has same value - so I can't used that.

UPDATE: The getPurchases method on Android client is not returning the old subscription after upgrade. I wonder if there is a way to recognise it through the Google Play Developer API call.

Comment: Is it possible to get the delta price ? Meaning suppose the user pays X for plan A and he wishes to upgrade to plan B which costs Y. And so I wish to tell the user "you can upgrade to plan B for just (Y-X) price" .